# Rxjs how to use mergeMap?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, mapping, httprequest

**The task**

I have 3 observable `http1$` `http2$` `http3$` which are http requests.

> const http1$ = this.myService.someFnReturnAnObservale({});

I have another observable `isAuth$` as my stream source.
I need to get response from `http3$`.

**Context**

In order to make http3$, http2$ have to response something first.
Depend on `isAuth$` value, if it emits `true` then http2$ also has to wait http1$ to response something, if it emits `false`, then no need http1$.

*By something I mean either success or error, so I can apply some logic to it, and decide to stream to next observable or not.*

**Coding**

- create an observable to handle logic from http2$ to http3$

> ```
> const http23$ = http2$.pipe(
>     first(),
>     map(res => {
>        // some logic, return boolean flag
>     }),
>     catchError(err => {
>         return of(false); // in case http2$ response with error, also return false
>     }),
>     map(res => {
>         // if response (which is the flag above) is false
>         // pop an message
>         return res;
>     }),
>     filter(res => res === true), // only subscribe to http3$ after this
>     mergeMap(res => http3$),
> );
> ```

- I have 2 logic with the `isAuth$`, so:

> ```
> const initWithoutAuth$ = of(http23$); // no need http1$
> const initWithAuth$ = http1$.pipe(
>     first(),
>     map(res => {
>         // some logic, return boolean flag
>     }),
>     catchError(err => {
>         return of(false); // in case http1$ response with error, also return false
>     }),
>     map(res => {
>         // if response (which is the flag above) is false
>         // pop an message
>
>         return res;
>     }),
>     filter(res => res === true), // only subscribe to http23$ after this
>     mergeMap(res => http23$)
> );
> ```

- Whenever `isAuth$` emits new value, I'd like to cancel the current stream and start using another

> ```
> isAuth$.pipe(
>     switchMap(res => // does this really cancel curernt stream (http requests) to start over within the other one?
>         res ? initWithAuth$ : initWithoutAuth$
>     )
> ).subscribe(
>     res => {
>         console.log(`init`, res); // not the desired result yet
>     },
>     err => {}
> );
> ```

- I expect `http3$` response when I subscribe at last step, but I got a weird observable.
- How can I handle http observable response error properly in this situation? (duplicated code whenever I try to handle response and catch error of previous one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is wrong is this line

```
const initWithoutAuth$ = of(http23$);
```

With this line you basically say that `initWithoutAuth$` is an Observable which notifies (emits) another Observable, i.e. it notifies `http23$`.

It looks to me that `initWithoutAuth$` should be simply set to `http23$` and not to `of(http23$)`.

If you do this, you can also remove `catchError` from `initWithAuth$` and `initWithoutAuth$` and add it to the final Observable chain, like this

```
isAuth$.pipe(
    switchMap(res => // does this really cancel curernt stream (http requests) to start over within the other one?
        res ? initWithAuth$ : initWithoutAuth$
    ),
    catchError(err => {
        return of(false); // in case http1$ or http2$ response with error, also return false
    }),
).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log(`init`, res); // not the desired result yet
    },
);
```

As last note. I think that the `first` operator you use after each http call is not required. The http client returns an Observable which notifies at most just 1 value and then completes, so the `first` operator is redundant.

Comment: Thank you @Picci for replying my question. It does work on http3$ after removing of().
I'm not sure what do you mean last operator.

Comment: @Ivar_the_clueless Apologies, I wrote "the `last` operator" while I meant the `first` operator. You are using `first` after any http call. I think that that `first` is redundant for the reason I put in my answer. I update my answer in order to avoid further puzzling.